# How to figure out if a type supports equality operator

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm generating code that needs to check equality using `SyntaxGenerator`

Sample:

```
if (property.Type.IsValueType || property.Type == KnownSymbol.String)
{
    if (property.Type.TypeKind == TypeKind.Enum ||
        property.Type.GetMembers("op_Equality").Length == 1)
    {
        var valueEqualsExpression = syntaxGenerator.ValueEqualsExpression(
            SyntaxFactory.ParseName("value"),
            SyntaxFactory.ParseExpression(fieldAccess));
        return (IfStatementSyntax)syntaxGenerator.IfStatement(valueEqualsExpression, new[] { SyntaxFactory.ReturnStatement() });
    }
    ...
```

Problem is that this does not handle types such as `int`.

Guess I'm looking for something like `SupportsValueEquals(ITypeSymbol symbol)`

How can I figure out if a type supports equality via `==`?

Comment: You're already special-casing enums - just special-case the other built-in types that have built-in equality operators?

Comment: Beware that you can have more than one equality operator in any type.

Comment: That's actually a very good question, because the C# spec has no very obvious notion of "value equality". There's reference equality, and there's predefined equality, but that doesn't cover all notions of "value equality". For example, `Struct.Byte` has no `op_Equals` and `byte` has no predefined equality operator, but applying `==` to `byte` works anyway because there's an implicit promotion to `int`, which *does* have predefined equality. I wonder why the syntax generator bothers with this in the first place. How does it propose distinguishing flavors of `==` (and why)?

Comment: @JeroenMostert Absolutely. This could also happen with your own `struct ColoredInt32` which does not have an `operator ==` overload but has instead an `implicit operator int` which makes an expression like `oneColoredInt32 == anotherColoredInt32` legal.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: I was just about to post that. :-) Under the covers, both the C# and the VB syntax generators even produce the same expressions for both `ValueEqualsExpression` and `ReferenceEqualsExpression`. Maybe the distinction was intended for languages where there truly is a syntactical difference, but in that case, you simply need to know what language you're targeting to know what to generate. So I'd say this is a defect in the API if it does not actually offer a `SupportsValueEquals` somewhere.

Comment: What happens if you blindly call `ValueEqualsExpression`, always? Does any code complain if there's only reference equality on the types? If there is, that code should contain the check in its bowels somewhere and you can steal it. My hypothesis, however, is that nothing will actually fail unless the type has no support for equality *at all*, where `ReferenceEqualsExpression` also wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As Skeet suggested I ended up specialcasing all the things:

```
private static bool HasEqualityOperator(ITypeSymbol type)
{
    switch (type.SpecialType)
    {
        case SpecialType.System_Enum:
        case SpecialType.System_Boolean:
        case SpecialType.System_Char:
        case SpecialType.System_SByte:
        case SpecialType.System_Byte:
        case SpecialType.System_Int16:
        case SpecialType.System_UInt16:
        case SpecialType.System_Int32:
        case SpecialType.System_UInt32:
        case SpecialType.System_Int64:
        case SpecialType.System_UInt64:
        case SpecialType.System_Decimal:
        case SpecialType.System_Single:
        case SpecialType.System_Double:
        case SpecialType.System_String:
        case SpecialType.System_IntPtr:
        case SpecialType.System_UIntPtr:
        case SpecialType.System_DateTime:
            return true;
    }

    if (type.TypeKind == TypeKind.Enum)
    {
        return true;
    }

    foreach (var op in type.GetMembers("op_Equality"))
    {
        var opMethod = op as IMethodSymbol;
        if (opMethod?.Parameters.Length == 2 &&
            type.Equals(opMethod.Parameters[0].Type) &&
            type.Equals(opMethod.Parameters[1].Type))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Please comment if you spot dumbs.

Comment: You're currently only handling types with *exactly one* `==` overload. What if there are multiple?

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks! Was mentioned in comments but I managed to dumb it any way.

Comment: The last three cases `IntPtr`, `UIntPtr`, and `DateTime` are technically wrong when it comes to C#. The C# Language Specification knows of no `operator ==` for any of them. In each case, the C# compiler searches for a user-defined operator instead, and finds one. So these should be omitted, just as `TimeSpan`, `Guid`, and other non-predefined types are omitted. Also, `System.Enum` is a reference type, just like other classes, and it should not be a `case` label on your switch section.

Comment: Also, one might want to consider delegate types specially, since they have special mention in the C# Language Specification. Each delegate type is a reference type, but `==` goes to a special overload that is defined by the C# spec. They are more or less in the same "category" as `System.String` (a reference type as well).

Comment: Missing from this (possibly, depending on intended semantics) is the case where the type is a `struct` and has an implicit conversion operator to any numeric type (`sbyte`, `byte`, `short`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`, `decimal`, `float`, `double`). In this case, there exists an equality operator by virtue of implicit numeric promotions. But, of course, this is specific to C#.

Comment: Ah, actually, implicit conversions to *any type* with a predefined equality operator (like `bool` and `string` but not, oddly enough, enum types, which looks like a bug to me); the numeric conversions take care of types like `byte`.

Comment: New suggestion: Drop the stuff I said about delegate types, and drop `System_String` and `System_Enum`; instead have `if (type.IsReferenceType) { return true; }` since `==` will be allowed on any reference type, falling back to reference equality if no other overload matches better. And use `if (type.TypeKind == TypeKind.Enum || type.TypeKind == TypeKind.Pointer) { return true; }` to support pointer types (such as `void*`, `char*`, `MyStruct*` etc.) as well.

Comment: I want `==` for string but want to generate ReferenceEquals for other reference types as it is clearer imo. The question is for [this](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/WpfAnalyzers) project btw.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Your parenthesis in the latest comment is interesting! I do not know if it is a bug, but it appears to have been the same in the pre-Roslyn compiler (Visual C# 5.0). Also if you have an implicit conversion to a reference type other than `string`, such as `System.Exception` (does not overload `==`) or `System.Uri` (overloads `==`), then the compiler will also not do the conversion automatically. The rules for Overload resolution (§7.5.3) and Function member invocation (§7.5.5) are technical. Maybe I should ask a separate question on this?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: I was working on the same thing, actually, because the standard actually explains why this doesn't work for enums (section 7.3.4, second para, last sentence) but by that same sentence it shouldn't work for delegates and it does! I can explain why it doesn't work for other types like `Exception` or  `Uri`, though: if the struct does not define an equality operator itself, only predefined equality operators are considered (7.3.4 second para again). It doesn't matter if it converts to a type that implements an equality operator, those operators are not candidates.